# What do you call a man who desires to have a lifelong, non-sexual but intimate relationship with a woman?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, terminology

1. The man lives in the same house with a woman but he never has sex or desires to have sex.
2. He is comfortable being nude with her and so is she, but there is no sexual touching or lust.
3. He cuddles her and they do things socially together.
4. He sleeps in the same bed with her but without any sexual contact.
5. He supports and provides for her, but they are not married or joined together.
6. He deeply loves the woman but cannot marry her.

Comment: @Jasper: In light of the comments after it, I assumed you were just being light-hearted too. I don't really think it's justifiable to close this as "too localised". In the whole world, there will be millions of people in such situations - not all of whom will be really old men who are simply "past it".

Comment: @Jasper: I'm sure they can. Many of us have quite "intimate" relationships with our pets - who we love, cuddle, and play together with. But most of us don't have sexual relations with our pets. Asexuals don't experience lust or sexual desire - but other than that, they can be perfectly normal human beings in terms of social/emotional relationships.

Comment: This is a pretty specific set of criteria (live together, cannot marry, cuddles, asexual, sleep together, ...). Is the situation common enough for you to expect a specific term? Is there a cultural stereotype or just an example in the media that you can give? Do you have a slang term for it?

Comment: An adjective to describe their relationship (or the person) is [platonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_love).

Answer (score 6):

As the comments indicate, such men are sufficiently uncommon that we probably don't have a special noun for them, but the generic term is

> [asexual](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/asexual) - *2. free from or unaffected by sexuality: an asexual friendship.*

Note that *asexual* is normally an adjective, but [it is used as a noun](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110222114011AAWDgi1) too.